# Is it possible to interleave execution of multiple delegates on a single thread?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a function that looks like this:

```
void ExecuteInterleave(Action a, Action b) {
    ...
}
```

that will automatically execute `a` and `b` interleavingly on the *current thread*? For example, `a` would run for a few hundred milliseconds, then `b` would run, repeat. It would block the current thread until both `a` and `b` have returned.

This question is purely from a theoretical standpoint, as I'm curious if it's possible.

Comment: That makes little sense, the "current thread" is busy executing ExecuteInterleave().  You can do `a(); b(); a(); b();` but doubtful that's what you are looking for when you talk of "few hundred milliseconds".

Comment: Years ago I used a [protothread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protothreads) implementation to do this on 16-bit CPUs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatically - no since there is no way for current thread to magically stop executing a method.

If you can get delegates to cooperate in multitasking - doable. Cool looking approach would be to use `yield return` in each delegate to and driver method would iterate  both "sequences" in order it wants.

```
IEnumerable<int> A()
{
   // cooperative step 1    
   yield return 0;
   // cooperative step 3    
   yield return 0;
}

IEnumerable<int> B()
{
   // cooperative step 2
   yield return 0;
   // cooperative step 4    
   yield return 0;
}

void ExecuteInterleave(Func<IEnumerable<int>> a, Func<IEnumerable<int>> b) {
 var i1 = a().GetEnumerator();
 var i2 = b().GetEnumerator();

 i1.MoveNext();
 i2.MoveNext();
 i1.MoveNext();
 i2.MoveNext();
}
...
ExecuteInterleave(A, B);
```

Comment: This is similar to a simplified version of the Caliburn.Micro coroutines model that was using an enumeration of `IResult` instances, that it used before awaitable / async was introduced. I rather like this approach.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you could potentially handle this would be to make the `Action` passed in be comprised of `async void` defined methods.

By strategically using `await` within the methods, they could yield execution back to the current synchronization context.  If the current context was one that forced executing on the current thread (ie: a UI dispatcher context), this would cause the two methods to potentially interleave on the same thread.

Note that this is not the same as saying "let `a` execute for 400ms, then switch to `b`, then back, as this would be fully cooperative and require the methods in question to explicitly yield control.